# Making a copy of an image via a Loop not working

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

Idk why the code won't work. All it does is give me a blank white image. And if you don't declare a matrix before by zeros(x, y) then it works fine. Wth is wrong here?

I tried not declaring the zeros matrix before and only that works. I even tried doing img2(i,j) = img2(i,j)+img1(i,j)

```
function [imgOut] = scaleLoopBased(img,s)
%UNTITLED4 Summary of this function goes here
%   creating a zero matrix of the given scale
[rows,columns]=size(img);
imgTemp=zeros(rows, columns);

for i=1:rows
    for j=1:columns
        imgTemp(i, j) = img(i, j);
    end
end

imshow(imgTemp);

imgOut = imgTemp;
end
```

Blank white image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of your new image (of type [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html), what [`zeros`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) creates by default) not having the same type as your original image (typically type [`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html)). You can fix this by initializing your new image to have the same data type as the original using the [`class`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) function and passing [an additional argument to `zeros`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html#btovuwl-typename):

```
imgTemp = zeros(rows, columns, class(img));
```

The reason it works correctly when you don't initialize `imgTemp` is because MATLAB initializes the variable for you using the data type of `img` by default when you perform the first indexed assignment.

The [`imshow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) utility expects one of the standard [image types in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html). An image of type `double` is expected to have values spanning the range `[0 1]`, while images of type `uint8` will have values in the range `[0 255]`. In your example you likely have a matrix `imgTemp` that is of type `double` but has values spanning `[0 255]`. Another way to fix your issue is to explicitly tell `imshow` what value range to use for the display (since the default `[0 1]` doesn't work):

```
imshow(imgTemp, [0 255]);
```

Always be aware of the data type when manipulating or processing images. You may need to scale or convert back and forth, using a `double` type for calculations (since integers saturate) and a `uint8` type for display and reading/writing to files.